# Wrong wording in error message when running out of daily flags count

Tags: bug, flags, error-message

I ran out of flags, the error message is shown for further flags as

> you can flag for mod's attention only x times a day.

Even if I raised some other flags.

[image]

> Here I am raising a duplicate flag, which will push it into Close Vote review queue.

But the error message shown is

[image]

Then I checked it in Travel Stack Exchange to check whether it applies only in Stack Overflow or not.

And the same happens in Travel too.

[image]

and the message is

[image]

But in both 2 cases, I didn't flagged for moderator's attention. I flagged it with Closure recommendation and it will go to Close Vote review queue.

So the message should be something like

[image]

Comment: IIRC, in the past, *all* flags went directly to diamond mods.  Then, as the site grew, they slowly offloaded most types of flags to users with sufficient reputation.  Mods still handle e.g. NAA flags that have been in the queue for over an hour, but many flags are handled by regular users nowadays, so I agree that this should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments by [*NobodyNada*](/u/258777),

> IIRC, in the past, all flags went directly to diamond mods. Then, as the site grew, they slowly offloaded most types of flags to users with sufficient reputation. Mods still handle e.g. NAA flags that have been in the queue for over an hour, but many flags are handled by regular users nowadays.

Because *they slowly offloaded most types of flags to users with sufficient reputation*, we now have Review Queues, mostly the VLQ queue and CV queue.

Nowadays "*in need of moderator intervention*" (with a custom reason) are the only kind of flags that are handled directly by ♦ mods. The other kinds of flags will have to wait for some time (or reviews) before they go directly into diamond mod's attention, so as to relieve pressure on ♦ mods.

However the message might be a part too minor that it got ignored during the growth of the site. I agree that it's time to change the message.

Comment: Mods also get spam/abusive flags and comment flags, and some auto flags. There's also an option to ignore the delay on VLQ/NAA flags and see them straight away

Comment: @Cai AFAIK that's optional. You don't automatically get those "regular" flags unless you opt-in to get them. However I have no idea about comment flags.

Comment: I'm a mod so I do know :) we do get all of those flags, the only optional part is the delay on VLQ/NAA flags

Comment: @Cai I mean, outside of the Review Queue.

Comment: Yeh we get all of those as mod flags, separate from the review queues